# FCM - Get Message Label

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

To send a message from FCM backend, we have this view :

[image]

I wanna to get the **message label** (*libellé du message*) from `RemoteMessage`. When I debug for the field, the content in the message is labeled as `google.c.a.c_l`, which I think is an internal field.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I just wonder the same as your question. But after read the document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) and played around with it, I found that:

- You cannot get the message label on client device, because it is just a label for display on firebase console only.
- To get title at client side, you have to use **Advanced options** which is auto collapse at the bottom. With Advanced options, you can also send a data payload to the client by key/value.
- Then `remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()` for notification's message body (from Message text/Texte du message), `remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()` for notitifcation's title (from Advanced options), `remoteMessage.getData()` for data payload (from Advanced options).

Answer (score 1):

Try to get it with `remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()`. However, check before if `remoteMessage.getNotification() != null`.

Hope this helps.